# how to not duplicate react i18next in each component

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

i start to use I18next to my react app. - > https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks

i using with theyre hook {useTranslation}

but the problem and annoing situation is that i need to write it over and over again in every component:

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";//////////////this
 const example = () => {
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();////////////////// and this
return (
    <>
        <p>{t("Thanks.1")}</p>
```

its look weird that this is the way to implement it,
there is a way to declare it globally and just reuse it in all my app?

Comment: You can create un HOC (High Order Component)  that pass method to all children components. Theses components has just to get the prop and call the method.

Comment: its gonna work with functional components?

Comment: I think an HOC can be a functionnal component but its implementation can be a little bit complicated especially in typescript

Comment: but is doesnt help to me, i need to pass props to any component... its also look messy...to add props to every compoennt { t, i18n }. look weird

Comment: It is not a magic trick, you need an access to the `t` function in order to translate, there are 2-3 ways to do so, 1. useTransaltion hook, 2. withTranslation HOC, 3. import the instance directly (not recommended in React apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export const ExampleComponent_2 = ({t}) => {
 return (
   <p>{t("Thanks.2")}</p>
    )
  }


export const ExampleComponent_2 = ({t}) => {
 return (
   <p>{t("Thanks.1")}</p>
   )
 }
```

in top container use it

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export const App = ({ t }) => {
  return (
  <ExampleComponent_1 t={t}/>
  <ExampleComponent_2 t={t}/>
 )
}
```